# Cookies expiration not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

Im trying to make a persistent cookie using C# 4.0 and this code:

```
HttpCookie AssoCookie = new HttpCookie("AssociateCode", AssociateCode);
AssoCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(AssoCookie);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and the cookie is session expiring. If I use Web Developer plugin in Firefox to check it I can see this info:

```
Name    AssociateCode
Value   test
Host    localhost
Path    /
Secure  No
Expires At End Of Session
```

The cookie I'm doing as a test its just created on there, noone else manages it or edits it so it cannot be overwritten. I have nothing set in webconfig to set cookies expiration (anyway this should override that) and if I set some cookies expiration time it doesnt work.

I'm a bit lost now, every manual, tutorial, blog, whatever I check says you just have to set the Expiration date, Ive debugged, Ive checked that it really has that value when created and at the end of Page_PreRender but it just expires with session whatever I do.

Any ideas?

Im using Firefox 9.0.1 btw.

**Update**

Using Firebug plugin in Firefox to check response headers I get this:

```
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control   private
Connection  Close
Content-Length  21322
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Mon, 23 Jan 2012 16:47:08 GMT
Server  ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Set-Cookie  AssociateCode=test; expires=Mon, 23-Jul-2012 16:09:04 GMT; path=/
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
```

And using Fiddler I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: AssociateCode=; expires=Mon, 23-Jul-2012 16:27:29 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 23 Jan 2012 17:27:29 GMT
Content-Length: 21313
```

** Update 2 **
Im checking that the Cookie doesnt exist just checking between my Firefox's cookies, but, in case you want to see how I get it later in code (not necessary since it not on there anyway):

```
try {
    AssociateCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("AssociateCode").Value;
} catch { }
```

Comment: Are you sure the cookie itself is expiring or does it appear to be expiring because of the way the session is behaving? After session expiration during debug, is the cookie physically no longer attached to the request?

Comment: If I close the browser window and open it again the cookie disappears. And that happens without requesting anything to the page. So its expiration date really is "End of Session".

Comment: I tested and had no problem.  The browser remembered the cookie even after closing it and opening it back up again.  I would suggest using Fiddler to just double check that the cookie is really being sent to the browser with the proper expiration header and the browser is properly sending it back to the website after closing/reopening.

Comment: Hi, I use Firefox's "Web Developer" plugin to check cookies and also Chrome tools to check them and I can see they havent the correct Expiration Date. What is Fiddler and how would it be an advantage in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com "Fiddler") is a utility that logs all traffic to and from your comp. It allows you to see exactly what was sent and received from your web page. Install it and run your page, you'll be able to see what was sent.

Comment: Updated on the post. It seems the headers are right, so, how can that happen? And it happens with every browser...

Comment: I get the feeling that you are testing for the existence of the cookie incorrectly.  Can you post the your code that shows you don't have one?  Read this: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/02/multiple-duplicate-cookies-and-one.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok everybody. I am so sorry but it seems for some reason I had configured my browsers time ago to delete cookies when I closed windows, so, despite Cookies were being created properly the browser setted them as session cookies not because they were but because of browser options.

In fact, if I went to manage Cookies in Firefox, I could uncheck the option "Session Cookie" in a cookie and then the Expiration Date was the correct one, but for some reason that check option was checked by default. I thought that maybe there was a way to set if a Cookie is Session Cookie or not, or maybe .Net was doing something until I realized this.

Well, when nothing logic seems to work, you know the problem is the most stupid thing you could imagine...

Sorry again.

Comment: No problem for me, I have the same error and now I can try these solutions, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just to follow up with my comment:

The info from fiddler and firefox's tools show that you are sending the correct information to create the cookie.

This leads me to believe that you are incorrectly testing it's existence.

When testing if a cookie is passed to your application you should use the `Request.Cookies` container to see if it's there.  (note that it is ***REQUEST*** not **RESPONSE**).

If you test by using something like:

```
if (Response.Cookies["mycookie"] == null) { .. }
```

Then this will cause a new cookie in the response object to be created that is blank.

To sum up: the Request object will contain everything sent from the browser.  The Response object is everything you are sending to the browser.

Comment: Yeah, thats a nice tip, it can happen sometimes. But I know the difference between Request and Response and this is not the case. In fact, I only need to close and open the window, search for the cookie in Firefox's Cookies and it is disappeared, or using Web Developer plugin, it doesnt exist. So, I dont even need to check if it exists using .Net, and if I do, I use Request instead of course.
|| Ex: try { AssociateCode = Current.Request.Cookies.Get("AssociateCode").Value; } catch { }

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the SetCookie function instead of Add?

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(10);
HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Just tested this quickly and it works for me.

Comment: Nice try, Ive checked it and doesnt work. It has to be some type of IIS config or something im missing. Can someone at least confirm me that this should work? Im starting to doubt it now...

Comment: Yes, this should work. Can you post the HTTP response (Set-Cookie header) so we can see exactly what the server is emitting?

Comment: SetCookie is undefined, did you mean using Set rather than SetCookie?