# .net Cookie dissapears after session Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, session, cookies, timeout

I have a bit of a problem handling cookies/session timeout, i need a persistent cookie to expire not at session timeout, but after. The problem is, that when the .net session dissapears after timeout, the cookie value is not being found, here's the code i use to set the cookie and to retrieve it.

Code that sets the cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookiecontext = new HttpCookie("cookiecontext");
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        cookiecontext["Context"] = "MB";
                        cookiecontext.Expires = now.AddHours(5);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookiecontext);
```

Code that gets the cookie at errorout page when timeout happens (VerifyCookie() function clears the cookie after using it):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookiecontext"] != null )
                    {
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookiecontext"]["Context"] == "MB")
                        {
                            controllerOwn = (IController)AppContextMobile.ApplicationContext.GetObject(controllerName.ToUpper());
                            VerifyCookie();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            controllerOwn = (IController)AppContextWeb.ApplicationContext.GetObject(controllerName.ToUpper());
                        }
                    }
```

Do you have any idea why the cookie is not considered after the timeout? for me this code should have done the trick, but apparently it does not.

Thanks in advance to everyone that reads this question.

**Edit:** Adding some info, im working with Asp.net Mvc 2, the idea of the code is to recognize wether if the user is in a mobile or web environment, to show him the appropiate timeout page styled for each of them, as all my variables died after timeout, cookies were my only option left, Idk why i cant use Request.cookies or response.cookies directly, it only allows me to use HttpContext.current.Response/Request.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PBT.Models;
using PBT.Models.Interfaces.Mobile.ViewEngine.Configurator;
using PBT.ViewEngine.Configurator.Modules;
using PBT.ViewEngine.Configurator.Modules.Utilities;

namespace PBT.Controllers.Factory
{
    public class QuieroControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
    {
        #region Members of IControllerFactory

        public IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            try
            {
                IController controllerOwn;

                string Ruta = controllerName + "/" + GetAction(requestContext);

                if (Ruta.Equals("Home/WelcomePage")) 
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Canal"]) == "MB")
                    {
                        HttpCookie CookieContext = new HttpCookie("CookieContext");
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        CookieContext["Context"] = "MB"; //User in a mobile environment
                        CookieContext.Expires = now.AddHours(5);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(CookieContext);

                        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Context", "MB");
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToString(requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Canal"]) == "HB")
                    {
                        HttpCookie CookieContext = new HttpCookie("CookieContext");
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        CookieContext["Context"] = "HB"; //User in a web environment
                        CookieContext.Expires = now.AddHours(5);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(CookieContext);

                        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Context", "HB");
                    }
                }

                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["context"] != null)
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["context"] == "MB")
                    {
                        controllerOwn = (IController)AppContextMobile.ApplicationContext.GetObject(controllerName.ToUpper());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       controllerOwn = (IController)AppContextWeb.ApplicationContext.GetObject(controllerName.ToUpper());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieContext"] != null)
                    {
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieContext"]["Contexto"] == "MB")
                        {
                            controllerOwn = (IController)AppContextMobile.ApplicationContext.GetObject(controllerName.ToUpper());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            controllerOwn = (IController)AppContextWeb.ApplicationContext.GetObject(controllerName.ToUpper());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        controllerOwn = (IController)AppContextWeb.ApplicationContext.GetObject(controllerName.ToUpper());
                    }
                }

                return controllerOwn;
            }
            catch (Spring.Objects.Factory.NoSuchObjectDefinitionException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }


        }

        public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            if (controller is IDisposable)
            {
                (controller as IDisposable).Dispose();

            }
            controller = null;
        }

        #endregion

        private static string GetAction(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);
        }

        public void VerifyCookie()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["CookieContext"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("CookieContext");
                myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your asking why does the cookie dissapear when its gone???

Comment: can you check the `if (Response.Cookies["cookiecontext"] == null)` this sounds like a previous `SO` question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973628/cookies-expiration-not-working-in-c-sharp

Comment: The cookie and it's value should persist even after .net timeout, considering it has an expiration date, but when i try to get that value it does not exist.

Comment: I'll try that dj kraze, i'll tell you if it gives me any result, thanks

Comment: can you actually show the full method I wonder if the HTTPCookie object is at local scope also Your Cookie could be added like `Response.Cookies.Add(cookiecontext);` there is a difference between the two.. try changing it I had similar issues with Session[] object and HttpContext.Current.Session they work totally different

Comment: I thought about that but even after adding System.web at the start of the code it is not allowing me to use Response.Cookies, it recognizes it as wrong code, it only allows me to work on HttpContext.current

Comment: that can't be possible in a web form.. can you show what you are doing in that regard..?

Comment: Added some more info and the code