# Cookie expiration time not working in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

I cannot set a persistent cookie. It become session only.

I know the same problem have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973628/cookies-expiration-not-working-in-c-sharp) but I couldn't fix it even I did all the steps.
(Couldn't have test with Fiddler).

My code is:

```
/// Default.aspx.cs methods :

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (! Cookies.CookieExist("kuki"))
    {
        Cookies.CreateCookie("kuki");
    }
    Fill();
}    

private void Fill()
{
    string a = Cookies.GetCookieValue("kuki", "key");

    if (!a.Contains("data"))
    {
        return;
    }
    // codes for a
}

protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        Cookies.InsertCookie("kuki", "key", TextBox1.Text);
    }        
}


/// Cookie class methods:

public static void InsertCookie(string Cookie, string Key, string Data)
{
    HttpCookie Kuki = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Cookie];
    Kuki[Key] = Data;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(Kuki);
}

public static bool CookieExist(string Cookie)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Cookie];
    if (cookie == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public static void CreateCookie(string Cookie)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(Cookie);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
}

public static string GetCookieValue(string CookieName, string CookieKey)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[CookieName];
    try
    {
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            return cookie[CookieKey].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "";
    }        
}
```

I use Chrome.
How can I fix this ?

Update:

Added button and InsertCookie methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get what the error is. 
I was trying to store data on my cookie. 
But I should use my cookie only for a remember me method, for example.
Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
public static void CreateCookie(string Cookie)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(Cookie);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
}
```

Try

```
public static void CreateCookie(string Cookie)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(Cookie);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);   //<-- Add
}
```

Use [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) to add a cookie. Only use [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.set(v=vs.110).aspx) when you need to update a cookie that has already been written to the response (which is pretty much never).